# How to retrieve all the data stored in different tables in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables in my MySQL Database.

- orders
- items
- orders_items
- customers

**orders table**

order_id | customer_id

**items Table**

item_id | item_name | item_price | item_quantity

**orders_items table**

order_item_id | order_id | item_id

**customers table**

customer_id | customer_name

I want to display a table that lists all the orders from the order table with all the remaining data joined together.

Like this:

order_id | item_id | item_name | item_quantity | customer_id | customer_name | price

I use MySQL and PHP.

Comment: So what is your question here? Certainly you read about how to JOIN using SQL. Because you yourself use that term. So it is only natural to try to learn how to do it. Could you post your attempts here and point out where exactly your problems are? You certainly do not simply want others to make your work for you, do you?

Comment: Sure, no problem there. Welcome to your learning life! Certainly when beginning something you want to find out things. So where did you start to read? What did you try? Where did you get stuck so that you ask for help? You certainly tried to get started with this yourself, didn't you?

Comment: Nope. Really. I've been trying for almost one hour to solve it. Problem actually is I was using Medoo framework. Got a little bit stuck. That's it.
Now I see I am a really poor programmer. :(

Comment: Why do you claim to be a poor programmer? No reason for that! Getting stuck with issues is the best way to learn! Go on! And as said before: _post your attempts here_ so that you get specific help. That way you will learn much more than when simply taking a ready solution, cause then you will not really understand _why and how_ it works. Oh, and when you suspect some framework hindering you in your attempt, then do without until you have what you are looking for (SQL on CLI here). Then go forward to using your solution inside the framework.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. I will do learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to learn aboud joins:

```
select orders.order_id , items.item_id , item_name , item_quantity , customers.customer_id , customer_name , price 
from `orders` 
join `orders_items` on  orders.order_id = orders_items.order_id 
join `items` on  items.item_id = orders_items.item_id 
join `customers` on orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
`SELECT * FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id=orders.order_id 
LEFT JOIN items ON items.item_id=orders_items.item_id 
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id`
```